# Can't save image in JPG with white background OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, jpeg, alpha

I write a simple app in OpenCV that delete black background of an image and save it with white background in JPG. However, it's always saved with black background.

This is my code:

```
Mat Imgsrc = imread("../temp/temp1.jpg",1) ;
mat dest;
Mat temp, thr;

cvtColor(Imgsrc, temp, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(temp,thr, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

Mat rgb[3];
split(Imgsrc,rgb);

Mat rgba[4] = { rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2],thr };
merge(rgba,4,dest);
imwrite("../temp/r5.jpg", dest);
```

Comment: Save it as a PNG, because JPEG images can't support transparency.

Comment: thanks but i dont want transparency i want white color

Comment: Please attach sample input and expected output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `setTo` with a mask to set some pixels to a specific value according to a mask:

```
Mat src = imread("../temp/temp1.jpg",1) ;
Mat dst;
Mat gray, thr;

cvtColor(src, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

// Are you sure to use 0 as threshold value?
threshold(gray, thr, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

// Clone src into dst
dst = src.clone();

// Set to white all pixels that are not zero in the mask
dst.setTo(Scalar(255,255,255) /*white*/, thr);

imwrite("../temp/r5.jpg", dst);
```

Also a few notes:

1. You can directly load an image as grayscale using: `imread(..., IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);`
2. You can avoid to use all those temporary `Mat`s.
3. Are you sure you want to use `0` as threshold value? Because in this case you can avoid entirely to apply `theshold`, and set to white all pixels that are 0 in the grayscale image: `dst.setTo(Scalar(255,255,255), gray == 0)`;

This is how I'd do:

```
// Load the image 
Mat src = imread("path/to/img", IMREAD_COLOR);

// Convert to grayscale
Mat gray;
cvtColor(src, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY); 

// Set to white all pixels that are 0 in the grayscale image
src.setTo(Scalar(255,255,255), gray == 0)

// Save
imwrite("path/to/other/img", src);
```